# CPU Power Manager extension in Lubuntu

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I need the CPU Power Manager Gnome Shell extension in another DE.
I'm tired of Gnome but I neeeeed that ext. to stop the loud fans in my laptop.

Comment: There may be an equivalent replacement, but GNOME Shell extensions only work in GNOME, and can require specific versions of GNOME to work.  Likewise, LX extensions and apps can require a specific version of Lubuntu. What is the release number of Lubuntu you have installed? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I haven't install Lubuntu yet.

Comment: Which release do you _intend_ to install?